# Read 3 bytes from Bluetooth Address?

Tags: c++, iphone, bluetooth, byte, mac-address

LAP

Lower Address Part (3 bytes). This portion of Bluetooth Address is allocated by the vendor of device. The LAP value uniquely identifies a Bluetooth device as part of the Access Code in every transmitted frame.

But we only got 8, 16, 32 and 64 as unsigned integer. Is there a library or method to read 3 bytes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a structure to get the data that you want. Here is the [`BD_ADDR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495641.aspx) structure used by Windows Embedded.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
  typedef struct __bd_addr {
      union {
         struct {
          unsigned int LAP : 24; 
           unsigned int UAP : 8; 
       };
        unsigned int SAP; 
     };
      unsigned short  NAP; 
  } BD_ADDR;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

You can then access the LAP as a member of the structure. `BD_ADDR.LAP`